# get data within <li> tag beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are 3 li elements within a ul. Beautuful Soup is not showing the text within the li elements. 
The 3 li elements contain the Location, Phone Number and Fax number of an institute.

```
<ul>
    <li class="spacer">
        <span>
            Location:
        </span>
        <br></br>
        1500 S. 1st Avenue
        <br></br>
        Yuma, AZ 85364
    </li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <span>
            Phone Number:
        </span>
        <br></br>
        928-373-4700
    </li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <span>
            Fax Number:
        </span>
        <br></br>
        928-343-8864
    </li>
```

My script is:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.policelocator.com/az/yuma-police-department/"
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

data = soup.findAll('li',attrs={'class':'spacer'})
print data[0]
```

The output is:

```
<li class="spacer"><span>Location:</span> </li>
```

I can get to the particular li element but there is no location data. It is being omitted for some reason.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about the version of `BeautifulSoup` - it is about the [differences between underlying parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) `BeautifulSoup` uses:

> Beautiful Soup presents the same interface to a number of different
>   parsers, but each parser is different. Different parsers will create
>   different parse trees from the same document.

Demo:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
>>> print soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'spacer'})
<li class="spacer"><span>Location:</span> </li>

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html5lib')
>>> print soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'spacer'})
<li class="spacer"><span>Location:</span> <br/>1500 S. 1st Avenue<br/>Yuma, AZ 85364</li>

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
>>> print soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'spacer'})
<li class="spacer"><span>Location:</span> 1500 S. 1st AvenueYuma, AZ 85364</li>
```

As you see, different parsers - different results.

When you don't specify the parser explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` [will choose the best one](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

Comment: I guess you are right. My windows machine raises error if I use a parser other than 'html.parser'.

On my ubuntu machine, the output looks fine and 'html5lib' works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the version of BeautifulSoup you used. In my machine with BeautifulSoup4.3.2 and Py2.7, the output is

`<li class="spacer"><span>Location:</span> 1500 S. 1st AvenueYuma, AZ 85364</li>`

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6 and BeautifulSoup4. How can I find the specific BS version?

Comment: I also have BS 4.3.2 on my system. Could you suggest where the problem might be?

Comment: I just copy your code and got the output with location data. You may check the url returned raw content to find if there are those location data.

Comment: The problem is not version-related - it is parser-related.